# How to Compare a Value with all all table first tds in many table rows by returning true if exits?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table and I ant to compare a value that I have with all its first `TRs > TDs`.

I gave a class added to all the td I want to loop throught and compare with the given value ex: ID=77

I tried this but it didn't work...

**Javascript code**

```
function CheckIfExists2(EmployeeID) {
    var x = false;
    $("tr.rows").each(function () {
        var addedIDs = $(this).find("td.added").val();

        if (EmployeeID == addedIDs) {
            x = true;
        }
    });

    if (x == true) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

    return false;    
}
```

**Html**

```
<tbody id="AddedEmployees">
    <tr class="rows">
        <td class="added">267</td>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1500</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>        
    </tr>

    <tr class="rows">
        <td class="added">106</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>6980</td>
        <td>700</td>
        <td>320</td>
        <td>360</td>           
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: On a side note, I think not using `each`, but rather a normal `for-loop`,  which you can *break out off*, would be better for your purpose. This way you can simple return `true` on the first match. Currently you'll always compare every value even if, for example, the first was already a match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

value property is not associated to td elements.due to which `.val()` returns empty string. You need to use `.text()` instead of `.val()` to get the text content of element:

```
 var addedIDs = $(this).find("td.added").text();
```

Comment: Really thank you @Milind
Does .val(); works with inputs and .text(); works with another tags ?

Answer (score 0):

More clearly code:

```
function CheckIfExists2(EmployeeID) {
     var result = false;
     return $("td.added").each(function () {
         if($(this).text() == EmployeeID){
             result = true;
         }
     }).promise().then(function()
         return result;
     });
}
```

Comment: This will always return false, as the inner return will only return from the iterator-function.